# Swapping row of 2D string array in C

Tags: c

The module that swaps row to make an array sorted in ascii ascending order keeps returning error.

```
const int MAX = 10;
const int MAX_STR = 80;

void asciiOrder(char (*buffer)[MAX_STR]);

void asciiOrder(char (*buffer)[MAX_STR]) {

  char * temp;

  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(buffer) / sizeof (buffer[0]) - 1; i++) {

    for (int j = 1; i + j < sizeof(buffer) / sizeof(buffer[0]); j++) {

      for (int k = 0; k < strlen(buffer[i]) && buffer[i][k] != NULL; k++) {

        if (buffer[i][k] > buffer[i+j][k]) {

          temp = buffer[i+j];
          buffer[i+j] = buffer[i];
          buffer[i] = temp;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the error I got from the entire code:

```
practice102.c:87:23: error: assignment to expression with array type
           buffer[i+j] = buffer[i];
                       ^
practice102.c:88:21: error: assignment to expression with array type
           buffer[i] = temp;
```

I searched other posts but still don't know why.
How to solve this problem?

Comment: You can't swap two rows of a 2D array like that. You'll have to swap them element by element.

Comment: Did any of those posts you found mention anything about arrays not being assignable i(can't appear on the left side of an assignment operator `=`) in C ? They're not. And [`sizeof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof) doesn't work the way you seem to think it does.

Comment: `sizeof(buffer)` is just the size of a pointer, not the size of an array.

Comment: @WhozCraig I changed it into MAX, it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C forbidden to assign a 2D array without specify the two index.
You have to write something like

```
buffer[a][b] = buffer[c][d]
```

whatever your a,b,c,d are.

Also be sure that your buffer temp are filled and/or allocated.